# I would like to place transparent buttons with links on a graph

Tags: highcharts

I would like to thank Highcharts for always providing me with useful features.
I have one technical feasibility question.

We would like to place a couple of transparent buttons when the mouse hovers over a graph view, and would like to be taken to the settings screen for that graph. Is such an implementation possible? If so, we would like to see documentation on how to implement it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oot4h.png)

Thank you,

Seishin

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom functionality and there is no documentation for that.

However, you can easily achieve the wanted result, with using basic HTML, JS and CSS. For example:

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }]
});

const mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
const optionsContainer = document.getElementById('optionsContainer');
const optionsCloseEl = document.getElementById('optionsClose');
const chartOptionsEl = document.getElementById('chartOptions');

mainContainer.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  document.getElementById('customOverlay').style.display = 'block';
});

mainContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  document.getElementById('customOverlay').style.display = 'none';
});

function onBtnClick() {
  optionsContainer.style.display = 'block';
  chartOptionsEl.value = JSON.stringify(chart.userOptions);
}

buttons[0].addEventListener('click', onBtnClick);
buttons[1].addEventListener('click', onBtnClick);

optionsCloseEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  optionsContainer.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
}

#customOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.5);
}

#buttons {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

#optionsContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
}

textarea {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="customOverlay">
    <div id="buttons">
      <button class="button">edit</button>
      <button class="button">more</button>
    </div>
    <div id="optionsContainer">
      <textarea id="chartOptions"></textarea>
      <button id="optionsClose">close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bg51wmh8/

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your message.

I'll try your advice, Thank you, 

Seishin